# Compare values of one dictionary to keys of another dictionary

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have two dictionaries like one give below:

```
Dictionary 1:
keyIdDict {
    "Feb 5, 2015" =     (
        607
    );
    "Nov 9, 2009" =     (
        431,
        433,
        435
 );
}

Dictionary 2:
rollImageDict {
    607 = "/Users/betteruse/Pictures/iPhoto Library.photolibrary/Masters/2014/10/21/20141021-160023/06122009123.jpg";
    433 = "/Users/betteruse/Pictures/iPhoto Library.photolibrary/Masters/2014/10/21/20141021-160023/06122009124.jpg";
    417 = "/Users/betteruse/Pictures/iPhoto Library.photolibrary/Masters/2014/10/21/20141021-160023/06122009125.jpg";
    419 = "/Users/betteruse/Pictures/iPhoto Library.photolibrary/Masters/2014/10/21/20141021-160023/06122009126.jpg";
    421 = "/Users/betteruse/Pictures/iPhoto Library.photolibrary/Masters/2014/10/21/20141021-160023/06122009129.jpg";
    435 = "/Users/betteruse/Pictures/iPhoto Library.photolibrary/Masters/2014/10/21/20141021-160023/06122009130.jpg";
}
```

I want to replace value in 1st dictionary i.e `607` with `"/Users/betteruse/Pictures/iPhoto Library.photolibrary/Masters/2014/10/21/20141021-160023/06122009123.jpg"`

Final result expected :

```
keyIdDict {
    "Feb 5, 2015" =     (
        "/Users/betteruse/Pictures/iPhoto Library.photolibrary/Masters/2014/10/21/20141021-160023/06122009123.jpg"
    );
}
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
NSMutableDictionary *newDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[keyIdDict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop){
    NSArray *array = [rollImageDict objectsForKeys:obj notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]];
    [newDictionary setObject:array forKey:key];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have my mac to write the code but it is very simple, just follow the steps

First iterate the dictionary(Dictionary 1) and get the value in a variable

you will have something like

```
607 //first iteration
431,433,435 // second iteration
```

then Split that value again and iterate it again.

so now when you split and iterate you will have `607` as value, iterate for every value.

for every iteration fetch the value from other dictionary

done..

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a test but you can try this code

```
    NSMutableDictionary *newDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    for (NSNumber *rollNum in rollImageDict) {
        for (NSString *str in keyIdDict) {
            NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
            for (NSNumber *keyNum in keyIdDict[str]) {
                if (rollNum == keyNum) {
                    [temp addObject:rollImageDict[rollNum]];
                }
            }
            newDic[str] = temp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried your method. It works but it replaces entire array with image path.

Comment: I changed something,this way  the date of the corresponding cannot have duplicate Numbers in the array .

Comment: It crashed saying *** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x608000045d60> was mutated while being enumerated.

Comment: you must use NSMutableArray in dictionary 1,NSArray can't change after init

Comment: I am using NSMutableDictionary for both

Comment: I mean the array in the dictionary 1 not dictionary

Comment: No i am using NSMutablearray still getting the same issue

Comment: oh i know array can't read and modify at the same time,you can create a new dictionary like dictionary 1 to recive the result

Comment: i change the code ,the newDic is the Dictionary used to receive the result